# get back root with custom rom

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3, rooting, ssh, superuser

Not long ago I upgraded my Samsung Galaxy 3 (GT-i5800) with [Kyrillos' rom](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1431393) v10.6

It appears to use [CyanogenMod](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1101218) 7.3.0-RC3
Android 2.3.7

Some apps I often need to use, like SSHDroid, Terminal and Midnight Commander, often get "has been denied superuser permissions"

I see mention of a root option, to Enabled for ADB and/or Apps , but no way to get to such a settings page despite various suggestions.
http://www.cyanogenmod.org/blog/security-and-you

Comment: A Samsung Galaxy S3 using Android 2.3.7? That's RATHER OLD. >_<

Comment: Anyway, do you see a SuperSU or SuperUser app on your phone? Maybe you can configure the access there. Or perhaps it's in `settings > system`.

Comment: Could you also download Root Checker from Google Play and see if you still have root access?

Comment: @geffchang Yes, so is the GT-i5800 old too, if you look it up. CyanogenMod 7 (providing the *upgrade* to Android 2.3.7) is the newest for that model than functions reasonably well, and must say, am very pleased with it, compared with the stock ROM for that phone. Even has built-in SIP, wifi hotspot and other features we've could only work around with 3rd-party apps before, if at all.

Answer (score 0):

The SuperSU bundled with CyanogenMod 7 was somehow inaccessible to user root access requests, like with SSHDroid, Terminal Emulator and Midnight Commander, as I've mentioned.

[Forums confirm](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1905838) superuser permissions being denied to everything, and inability to get to its configuration. This was a later CyanogenMod design decision.

What finally worked for me was copying the latest [CWM-SuperSU-v1.93.zip](http://www.adbtoolkit.com/rooting/su/zip/#.UxmWtNxdVeQ) over to my SD card, rebooting into the "recover" mode CyanogenMod provides, and flashing from that ZIP.
http://www.adbtoolkit.com/rooting/su/zip/#.UxmWtNxdVeQ

Now, I can finally do things like clean out large files from /data/dalvik-cache/*.dex when internal space is badly needed temporarily, or other UNIXy things.